# How to execute the current line in PL/SQL Developer without selecting?

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I want to execute a line in the "PL SQL Developer" program without having to select it.

Up to the present moment I need to select the query line and press the F8 key.

Is there any way I don't need to select the line for my query?

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT;

SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS; --execute that line without selecting
```

I am using PL / SQL DEVELOPER version 14

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do that.

you should go to preferences then go to Windows Type -> SQL window.

check "Auto Select Statment".

but you must add to your query `";"`